# Databricks notebook pass in parameters return result

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks

Hi I am very new to Databricks and wanted some guidance. I trying to pass in some parameters into a Databricks Notebook and I want it to do some simple computations. For example, pass in two parameters, x and y => return x + y as a response. I tried looking into it but couldn't find anything concrete.

Comment: how do you call the notebook?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider looking into Databricks widgets.
Reference: https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html

Comment: If this is what you were looking for, please mark the answer as accepted.